# Написанный текст не отображается с новой строчки в QTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, qlineedit, qtextedit, pyqt6

Так-то у меня получилось, чтобы написанный текст в `QLineEdit` отображался в `QTextEdit`, но чтобы следующее слово отображалось с новой строчки в `QTextEdit` у меня не получается.

Помогите плиз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставьте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему как обычный текст.

> void QTextEdit::[**append**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#append)(const QString &text)
>
> Добавляет новый абзац с текстом в конец редактирования текста.

Замените

```
print(self.txt.setText(self.lineEdit.text()))
```

на

```
self.txt.append(self.lineEdit.text())
```

Comment: Все, получилось. Спасибо, большое!

Comment: @Евгений пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour